# How to look at more than 1 character at a time in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am brand new to Python (as you're about to see). I am trying to make a message encoder and decoder. My encoder converts characters into 5 symbols and I need my decoder to do the opposite but I can't figure out how to look at more than one character from a string at a time. I'm sure my method is very elementary, but I am hoping someone could show me how to do it with basics. Here's a snippet of the decoder:

```
def decoder(message):
decoded_message = ""
for code in message:
    if code == "___.|":
        decoded_message = decoded_message + "a"
    elif code == "__..|":
        decoded_message = decoded_message + "b"
    elif code == "_...|":
        decoded_message = decoded_message + "c"
    elif code == "....|":
```

Comment: I recommend that you look up how to use a Python dict as a translation mechanism.  A Morse code translator is a good example.

Comment: For your particular problem, look up "Python string slicing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "*look at more than 1 character at a time*", what you want is to create chunks of length five which can be done as follows:

```py
for code in (message[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(message), 5)):
    pass  # do something with code
```

**Note:** If your `message` doesn't have a length which is a multiple of 5 in the last iteration `code` will not have 5 characters.

If you're going to do this a few times, you can also use

```py
chunks_of = lambda n, xs: xs and [xs[:n],*chunks_of(n,xs[n:])]
```

which you then use with `chunks_of(5, message)`.

Answer (score -1):

code = "abcdefg"

`code[i:j]` gives you substring from i to j-1
for example:
`code[1:4]` gives you "bcd"

```py
for i in range(len(message)-4):
    code = message[i:i+5]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can access string slices treating the string like an array in python. You can make use of the range method to give you the indexes like:

```
def decoder(message):
    decoded_message = ""
    for i in range(0,len(message),5):
        code = message[i:i+5]
        if code == "___.|":
            decoded_message = decoded_message + "a"
        elif code == "__..|":
            decoded_message = decoded_message + "b"
        elif code == "_...|":
            decoded_message = decoded_message + "c"
        elif code == "....|":
```